# On viewPager in Android is there way show large number of fragments?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager where I am using FragmentPageAdapter with page count as 3.

In my application I have a list of say numbers.
Suppose numbers are 99, 33, 44, 12, 7, 55, 77, 88, 45

I populate three numbers onto 3 fragments, say 12, 7, 55. 
Now at present, at app start, the number 12 shows up. Then user swipes to right and 7 shows up and then 55.

Is there a way on further swipe right another fragment appears showing next number 77, and if user swipes left he goes to 55, then 7, then 12. If user now swipes left again, he starts seeing next fragment with 44, then 33, etc.

In a way I manage my data window to just 3 numbers. But fragments should appear as if animated from left or right even when initially they were not there.

Is it possible in Android?

Also, please note that I get more data dynamically generated, so initially I do not have a good count on overall number to display.

---

### Let me make my question bit clearer.

Initial list has only 12, 7, 55. These are shown in viewPager. If 12 is showing up, and user swipes to right, he gets to see 7, and 55 (OK so far). Now, if user swipes right one more time, app gets more data (77, 88, 45) and that shows up. If now, user swipes to left, he sees 77, then 55, 7, 12. But beyond 12, if he swipes left again, then app gets more data on the left (99, 33, 44) and user can swipe left. All this while pager can maintain 3 fragments only (FragmentStatePagerAdapter). BUT can pager add fragments on left/right like the way I have described?

Comment: it is possible by default. There are no any additional manipulations required for that. The reason is that you implemented something wrong, but nobody knows what since only you see your code

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: Let me attempt to make my question bit clearer. My initial number list has only 12, 7, 55. These are shown in viewPager.

Comment: Vlad Matvienko - I am yet to code it. This is more of a conceptual question. See my edits please.